# Accessing tkinter keyboard input from controller class instead of GUI class

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

I am trying to create a GUI program made up of a controller class and a GUI class. Using tkinter, I have a keybind setup to check for wasd input. I need to get this keyboard input into my controller class so that I can control the functionality of the program.

Below is the rough structure of my code.

```
class gui(tkinter.Canvas) :
    def __init__(self) :
        self.bind_all("<Key>", self.keypress)

    def keypress(self, key) :
        event = key.char

class controller(object) :
    def __init__(self) :
        gui = gui()

    def control(self) :
        # code to use gui event input to control program.
```

This code probably doesn't work and I'm not looking for it to be used. This is just to show the structure of my application and my need to access the tkinter canvas keyboard input from the control method in the controller class.

Comment: Design seems odd.I don't think your `gui` should be a specialized kind of `tkinter.canvas`. It might _have_ one… Ignoring that, seems like it would need to be passed a `controller` instance so it could call its `control` method from its own `keypress()` method. Off-topic: If you're going to be using the Python language, I strongly suggest you read and start following [PEP 8 - Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), particularly its Naming Conventions.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the controller instance, and then pass that instance to the GUI.

```
c = controller()
g = gui(controller)
```

Within `gui` you should save a reference to `controller`, from which you can access the methods in the controller.

```
class gui(tkinter.Canvas):
    def __init__(self, controller):
        self.controller = controller
        ...
    def keypress(self, key):
        ...
        self.controller.control()
```